# SecurityServiceProvider Silex/Symfony authtentication

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm new to Symfony and Silex. I'm following the Silex docummentation and trying to implement login access for my app, but I have found struggling when trying to use the SecurityServiceProvider, even though I have tried many solutions here, none seems to work for me. The code I'm using is the following.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'annon' => array('pattern' => '^/'),
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
           //'anonymous' => true,
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/', 
                            'check_path' => 'admin/login_check',
                            'default_target_path' => 'admin/orders',
                            'always_use_default_target_path' => true),
            'logout' => array(  'logout_path' => 'admin/logout',
                                'target'  => '/',
                                'invalidate_session' => true),
            'users' => array(
                'admin@hotmail.com' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
        array('^/.+$', 'ROLE_USER'),
        array('^/.+$', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
        array('^/.+$', 'ROLE_LABOR'),
        array('^/annon$', ''), // This url is available as anonymous user
    )
));
```

so the users after logging in should be able to access everything after admin/.
PS: Do I ever have to implement the check_path route?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#securing-a-path-with-a-form).

The firewall definition `annon` can be removed.

There should be a Role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` usable in `security.access_rules`.